# What does "Activation" refer to in the context of the symptoms of Schizophrenia and Schizoaffective Disorder?

Tags: terminology, psychology

In this [journal article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21208586) certain symptoms are called "activation" in nature. I have never come across this term prior to coming across this article, so I would like to know quite simply what does it mean.

Comment: This question might be better placed over on [cogsci.SE] , and they could really do with some more questions

Answer (score 1):

The authors use the Positive and Negative Syndrome Scale (PANSS) to assess symptoms.  One of its cluster scores is activation factor.

Summary:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_Negative_Syndrome_Scale

Original publication of the article, which doesn't list activation factors:
http://schizophreniabulletin.oxfordjournals.org/content/13/2/261.long

Marketed currently here:
http://www.mhs.com/product.aspx?gr=cli&id=overview&prod=panss

None of the sources I saw specified what is meant by activation factor, and many didn't even mention it. It's possible that it's the hyperactivity mentioned in the original publication.  Also, it's possible that it's a modified category in the version sold at the last link. Hopefully this is enough information to get you started, if you want to hunt down the details.